# index/ingest very large json file to database with node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jsonp

I inherited a huge json file that I'm trying to index into elasticsearch (not really a database but don't get hung on es it should apply to most db ingest). I'm using node to do the ingest. I've tried streams and async but I'm stumped I have no frame for approaching this problem - without memory overflows and the like.

I can't post a 1 to 1 but it's effectively a multidimensional object that looks something like:

```
[ 
   { 
     document: {
        type: 1,
        type2: 2,
        type3: {...}
    },
    {...}
]
```

I just need to ingest the docs, I can use the elasticsearch client and process them in bulk.  I need to slow down the stream, parse, and chunk.

Totally stuck... Help stackoverflow it's Friday I want to go home ; ).

Comment: Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-parse-stream?

Comment: that may be the one version of json stream parsing I haven't tried, i'll try this one now.

Comment: ok making some progress with this one this module may be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on migg's suggestion of json-parse-stream - the third json stream library I tried - I finally have a working ingest.  Matter of fact it is running as I write this. Hopefuly someone will find this useful.

```
const fs = require('graceful-fs');
const parse = require('json-parse-stream');
const es = require('event-stream');
const client = new require('elasticsearch').Client();
var WritableBulk = require('elasticsearch-streams').WritableBulk;
var TransformToBulk = require('elasticsearch-streams').TransformToBulk;


var rs = fs.createReadStream('./resources/mydoc.json');

var bulkExec = function (body, callback) {
  console.log(body);
  client.bulk({
    index: 'my_index',
    type: 'my_type',
    body: body
  }, callback);
};

var toBulk = new TransformToBulk(() => { return { _index: 'my_index', _type: 'my_type' }; });


const done = (err, res) =>  {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(res);
  console.log('go get a drink you deserve it');
};

var ws = new WritableBulk(bulkExec);

rs.pipe(parse())
.pipe(es.mapSync(function (element) {
  var a =  [];
  if (element.key === 'document') {
    a = element.value;
    return a;
  }
}))
.pipe(toBulk)
.pipe(ws).on('finish', done);
```

Comment: Nice that you put your answer in here.